# Difference between "bisnipoti" and "pronipoti"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

What is the difference between "bisnipoti" and "pronipoti"? Do they mean the same?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Comment: Yes, they  mean the same: Pronipote: *Figlio o figlia di un nipote o di una nipote*, sinonimo di *bisnipote* (https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/P/pronipote.shtml).

Comment: Note that *pronipote* is also figuratively used to indicate the descendants of a family or dynasty.

Comment: Can you write all this as an answer, please, @Hachi?

Comment: Quite curiously, the Sabatini-Coletti proposes 14th century for *bisnipote* and 17th century for *bisnonno*.

Comment: @Charo - capisco ma questa domanda è veramente too basic. Basta consultare un dizionario. Per cui off-topic.

Comment: [Related meta question](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1345/when-are-monolingual-dictionaries-the-answer). In my opinion someone should write the answer, be they Hachi or someone else...

Comment: @egreg: Curious indeed. Zingarelli also gives, as first occurrences, 1306 for _bisnipote_ and 1698 for _bisnonno_.

Answer (score 4):

I see *bisnipote* attested from the 14th century and *bisnonno* from the 17th, which I find quite interesting and curious; *pronipote* is attested from the 15th century. (Source: Sabatini-Coletti.)

A *bisnipote* is usually a grandson's or granddaughter's child (in direct descent), whereas *pronipote* can also be used in extended meaning as a descendant of a collateral line. Somebody can be *pronipote* of a *prozio*: at some point the two have an ancestor in common with more than three steps. Two steps would make the two people *cugini*, three steps *zio/zia* and *nipote*. On the other hand, it's common in Italy to call *cugini* two people having in common a grandmother/grandfather.

*Prozio/prozia* is, according to the same dictionary, a mother's or father's uncle/aunt (17th century), but it's also used with more generations in between. However, if I had to address my mother's uncle, I'd simply use *zio*: *prozio* and, similarly, *pronipote* are rather formal and used for speaking of the person, not *to* the person.

Note that in Italian there is no distinction between *granddaughter/grandson* and *nephew/niece*: both are *nipote*.